# PnP modern search v3 - customizing the handlebars Cards/Tiles template in search results web part

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, pnp

I copied the Tiles template, added html and handlebars field objects and selected the custom layout option. All the data is there but the display keeps bouncing between the correct view and a broken view every time I refresh the page. My question is where exactly the custom code should go?
It works - albeit intermittently - when it follows this:

```
{{#> resultTypes item=item}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually put my handlebars template in a document library in a SharePoint site and reference it by URL using the "use an external template URL" field:

[image]

Comment: Thanks  - I actually meant where should I inject the custom code within the template. I'm not sure if where I've tried it is causing the issue or not.

Comment: Here is the detailed article on handlebar templates in SharePoint Online - https://global-sharepoint.com/sharepoint-online/how-to-customize-the-handlebars-template-in-pnp-modern-search-web-part/